# comando multi linea en Rstudio ver.RStudio para Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

En la versión previa de R yo podia escribir y ejecutar una linea de codigo así:

```
datos<-read.table("OlincaB.csv",header= T, sep=","
                ,quote="",fill = T,na.strings = "Na")
```

Es muy comodo cuando se esta enseñando el lenguaje.

Sin embargo actualmente me marca el error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "                  ,"
```

¿Hay forma de reactivar los comandos multilinea?

Comment: Por las dudas, revisa las opciones de configuración global, que en la solapa de "Code", el `ctrl-enter` funcione con la opción "Multiline R statement", aunque por el error pareciera ser otra cosa. Prueba también transformar el bloque en una sola linea y después vas insertando los "enters" para ir bajando el código, como para quedarnos seguros que no haya caracteres no imprimibles en el código original.